Google Tag Manager returns always 500 status to self-hosted gtm container
I've been trying to put in place server-side tagging on my website but the only error code Google Tag Manager returns is 500.
My nginx (behind a cloudflare https proxy) is made to reroute from the grasp endpoint :
        location /grasp {
                proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:5010;
                proxy_http_version      1.1;
                proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Connection $connection_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location /preview-grasp {
                proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:5015;
                proxy_http_version      1.1;
                proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Connection $connection_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

I've implemented using this docker compose configuration :
  google-tag-manager-preview:
    image: gcr.io/cloud-tagging-10302018/gtm-cloud-image:stable
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5015:8080"
    environment:
      RUN_AS_PREVIEW_SERVER: true
      CONTAINER_CONFIG: 'xxxxxx'
    networks:
      - network

  google-tag-manager:
    image: gcr.io/cloud-tagging-10302018/gtm-cloud-image:stable
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5010:8080"
    environment:
      PREVIEW_SERVER_URL: https://www.my-server.com/preview-grasp
      CONTAINER_CONFIG: 'xxxxxxx'
    networks:
      - network

In the nginx access logs, I see the 500 status response (so not cloudflare blocked), and in the gtm docker logs I see :
Sending aggregate usage beacon (see https://www.google.com/analytics/terms/tag-manager/): https://www.googletagmanager.com/sgtm/a?v=s1&id=xxxxxx&iv=24&bv=9&rv=4an1&ts=cl_gaaw_client!1*2.cl_gtm_client!1*2.ct_http!500*2.d_sfs!13*2.err_fps!22*2.http_d!200*2!400*2&cu=0.16&cs=0.00&mh=25170664&z

For my frontend, it is the regular third-party package issued by the nextjs team.
It should return 200 from what I saw on the internet.
There is no issue with my Google Tag Manager, I've published it.
No issue with any bills at Google.
THe preview instance doesn't fire any events, tags.
Kind of badly surprised by the lack of debugging information by the Google teams here.
